# Enhance the color associated with a band od an aerial photo?

Tags: qgis

I am using QGIS 2 on Windows 7 and have 4-band aerial photos loaded in to a project. I have switched the bands in order to make the photos display as color infrared. Does anyone know if you can enhance the color of the 4th band to make the red show better? I have a slight color blindness issue that hinders me seeing some of the red.

FYI... I am attempting to do a desktop analysis for a habitat assessment.

Comment: I guess it is doable by reading your images through GDAL virtual raster http://www.gdal.org/gdal_vrttut.html. Read about LUT and experiment a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you right-click the raster and go to properties, you have several color enhancement/editing tools you can work with. Two that might help you see things better are the saturation and the contrast enhancement. If you just want to make the red deeper, you can increase the minimum value under the histogram tab.

[image]